# implementation of async REST API server application

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I am a newbie in distributed computing and server side programming. Needed advice for implmenting a REST API server that serves JS clients. There may be multiple APIs (py1, py2, py3, etc). There may be multiple Javascript clients.

A client makes a API request that is non-blocking in nature. The response is delivered to the client asynchronously when done. The API implementations (python code themselves) would handle the request asynchronously in nature. A router like RabbitMQ routing can be used.

Need help with these questions:

1) Is this architecture the best representation of the requirements mentioned above ?

2) What is the best implementation for this for a highly scalable REST API Service ? I would prefer node and rabbitMQ. Alternative suggestions are welcome.

[Architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoXfi.png)

Comment: Maybe look at RPC if you want asynchronous responses rather than REST... Scalability isn't the issue you need to immediately solve. Do your own benchmarks on a single instance

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. How can I get a RPC combined with direct routing on rabbitmq ?